# Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request. in MVC3 Model Entities

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, model

I am new in MVC, made an app that works on my local machine (Windows 7 with SQLExpress) but when I deploy live on Windows 2008 R2, SQL 2008 R2 and IIS7, I get this error: "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request"

Below are snippets of the code in question:

WEB.CONFIG connectionStrings

```
add name="RentalEntities" connectionString="Data Source=[ServerName];Initial Catalog=[DatabaseName];Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

HOMECONTROLLER

```
namespace Rental.Controllers    
{    
   RentalEntities rentalDB = new RentalEntities();

   ...

   public ActionResult Index()

   {             
      var listings = from l in rentalDB.Listings select l;
      return View(listings.ToList());    
   }
}
```

HOME/INDEX.CSHTML

```
@model List<Rental.Models.Listing>

@foreach (var listing in Model)    
{    
    @listing.ListingName <br />     
}
```

The error occurred on this line `@foreach (var listing in Model)`, something to do with being null - note that NONE of the fields in the database are null. Any help will be appreciated.

---

Below is the full error message: [ where line 13 is: `foreach (var listing in Model)`

```
Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\projects\Rentals\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:line 13 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

Answer (score 0):

What has happened here is that you've passed a null value into the Model for `index.cshtml`.
The code is foreach'ing over `null`.

Debugging this in Prod:

- How many rows are in the Listing table on the Prod server?
- Does your LINQ To SQL .dbml refer exactly to the connection string in your web.config, or does it have a hidden connection string buried within the .designer.cs?
- Try setting up some debug info on INDEX.CSHTML

  ```
  @(Model==null) //will write to page whether the model data being passed is null.
  ```

Debugging this in Dev/Test:

- To help debug why it's null, set a breakpoint for yourself on the line in `Index()`.  Set it on `return View(listings.ToList());`. Is it actually null? Then set a breakpoint on the check for null in your View.

Before `foreach`, run a check for null:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
     foreach (var foo in Model)
     {
       //your code
     }
}
else
{
    @: Model Is null!
}
```

Comment: I did the above if else, and it did not like that part @"Model Is null!". When I removed it, it runs and shows nothing, which means the Model is null. Why is that? I have set the database and entities properly...

Comment: @Charl: see the update about your .dbml. I'd assumed you're using LINQ To SQL and not EF.

Comment: can you please elaborate on your last comment please, I don't understand what you mean when you say "see the update about your .dbml". Like you can see on my controller above, I used entities: RentalEntities rentalDB = new RentalEntities(); All of this worked on my dev and my friends computer locally... I am very new with MVC.

Comment: @Char: I meant that I'd updated my answer to include a bullet about .dbml. It's all about what connection string your .dbml is using. Check out your .dbml.designer.cs file. Does it have a connection string buried in the first constructor? See here: http://i.imgur.com/wbu0a.png