# MVC website encounters error if I navigate to full action address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC site in .NET 4.5 and if I navigate to Home/ (the entry point) all is well.

Inside my RouteConfig.cs file I have

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

In my controller, I have this method

```
//HomeController/Index
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Model m = BusinessLayer.GetData();
    return View(model);
}
```

Everything is fine if I point to /Home, but if I try to navigate to /Home/Index I get an error saying "An error occurred!"

No more useful information and no errors in the event log.

Note that everything works fine through Visual Studio, it is only when I deploy this to a testing server I encounter this error.

Comment: Try finding the exact error message by using this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100529/what-is-the-direct-cause-and-source-of-the-sorry-an-error-occurred-while-proce. Also, you may want to activate debug mode using `<compilation debug="true"/>` in `web.config`.

Comment: You'll need to temporarily configure IIS to return error details https://forums.asp.net/t/1209749.aspx?how+to+allow+web+application+to+display+error+message+on+remote+IIS+Server+